# Angular 4 Inherited Formcontrol

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am trying to create a subclass of FormControl with some additional properties which can then be used inside my custom form controls to change the behaviour.

I tried to inherit from FormControl(say StandardFormControl) as below and used to create a form group but when I access the formcontrol inside a directive/anywhere else, I do not get the properties of the subclassed form control.

```
class StandardFormControl extends FormControl{
   customProperty: string
}
```

The form group was created as below

```
new FormGroup({
  firstName: new StandardFormControl('',[])
});
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: how is it related, I am talking about reactive forms.

Comment: Tracking control state  is the way to make the form reactive

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know you have to typecast the form control:

```js
// first create the form group and store it in a variable:
const formGroup = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new StandardFormControl('',[])
});

// then you can access its controls:
(formGroup.get('firstName') as StandardFormControl).customProperty = 'customValue';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call super() in constructor to inherit the parent class.

```
class StandardFormControl extends FormControl{

    customProperty: string

    constructor() {
       super();
    }    
}
```